# выполнить условие если в url есть GET запрос

Tags: php, get

Как выполнить клик по кнопке или просто условие если в url есть GET запрос. https://домен/checkout/?checkout=5 если есть такой запрос имитировать клик по кнопке

Comment: РНР работает на сервере. Никаких "кнопок" там нет. Условие выполнить можно. if ($_GET['checkout'] == 5)

Comment: @Ипатьев
у меня в корзине есть кнопка удаления товаров. Можно ли как нибудь сделать клик по нему если есть get запрос?

Comment: @Ипатьев наверное я не правильно выразился. Очистить корзину если есть get запрос

Comment: ну так я и написал условие, по которому можно "очистить корзину". В чем проблема?